# ProtoDataStore Android: StrictMode policy violation, android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am trying to update a custom typed object using Android Proto Datastore like this:

```
fun updateTest(test: Test) =
    channelFlow<Test> {
        context.testDataSource.updateData {
            it.copy(
                test.a,
                test.b,
            )
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

I have wrapped the content in a flow and i have used a IO dispatcher as seen above.

Even after the dispatcher is changed I am getting a Strict policy error mentioned below

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=69 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1659)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
```

As far as the docs suggest we don't need to have read/write permission for proto data store in android and I am using a different thread other than Main.

I am collecting it like this in the viewmodel:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.updateTest(Test(a = "ABCD0000001"))
            .catch {
                // show error
            }
            .collect {

            }
    }
```

Not sure where the issue is. I have tried passing the Dispatcher to viewModelScope

> viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)

also but its also failing

Comment: have u solved issue?